# Can DailyRollingFileAppender roll logs at midnight instead of at next message?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am using log4j for my logging. I have a jetty based module. I need daily logging so I used the DailyRollingFileAppender. The thing is that I need the log file to roll on 12:00 A.M, at the moment it would wait for a new request before rolling, is there any way to "force" the rolling process?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it. The logging service would have to spawn a thread that waits all day or depend on some sort of timer service. Loggers try really hard not to have dependencies or to consume resources. Can your app log a message every day to trigger the rollover? Are you sure you want zero length log files for days with no messages? Otherwise, you probably need to subclass appender.

Comment: The thing there's at least around 300/400 transactions per day so regarding the last question I don't think there should be a problem, I'm trying to evade thread waiting. I think I'm going to stick to a crontab job that would send something at 12:00, I thought there could be something that can be done inside the log4j.properties file, oh well!

Comment: I'm open to further suggestions though!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're referring to Jetty's own logs, not your webapp's logs: you can override the base log directory with the `jetty.logs` system property.

Depending on how you start Jetty, it may be as simple as adding the property to your command line. For example:

```
java -jar -Djetty.logs=/var/log/search-service/jetty.system.log start.jar
```

or you can use log4j.xml file as below:

```
<appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="append" value="true" />
    <param name="maxFileSize" value="10MB" />
    <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="10" />
    <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <param name="fileNamePattern" value="${jetty.base}/logs/EZDataModeler_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log" />
    </rollingPolicy>
    <param name="file" value="${jetty.base}/logs/EZDataModeler_%d.log" />
    <param name="datePattern" value="'-'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" 
          value="%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] %c %x%n  %-5p %m%n"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>
```